# Cómo pasar como parámetro de una función la propiedad de un objeto a comparar o modificar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una función que ordena alfabéticamente por "titulo" un array, siendo "titulo" una propiedad de los objetos dentro del array. Además tengo la función inversa (Z -> A) de la misma.
La cuestión es que tengo varias propiedades dentro de cada objeto (Autor, Precios y más por venir) y me gustaría reutilizar esta función.

```
    const sortCatalogoAZ = () => {
    let Libreria = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Libreria"));
    Libreria.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.titulo > b.titulo) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.titulo < b.titulo) {
            return -1;
        }
        // Si son iguales
        return 0;
    });
    localStorage.setItem("Libreria", JSON.stringify(Libreria));
    showCatalogo(); //Lo imprimo
};
```

Como verán, para reutilizar la función necesitaría poder pasarle un parámetro a "sortCatalogoAZ" que resulte en la propiedad de "a.parámetro".
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los objetos también puedes accederlos haciendo `objeto[propiedad]`

Así que podrías pasar la propiedad que quieres usar como parámetro a tu función

por ejemplo:

```js
const Libreria = [{"titulo": "Titulo A","autor": "Autor C","precio": 0},{"titulo": "Titulo B","autor": "Autor B","precio": 2},{"titulo": "Titulo C","autor": "Autor A","precio": 1}];

const sortCatalogoAZ = (propiedad) => {

  Libreria.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a[propiedad] > b[propiedad]) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a[propiedad] < b[propiedad]) {
      return -1;
    }
    // Si son iguales
    return 0;
  });

}

sortCatalogoAZ("autor");

console.log(Libreria);
```